# I am getting out of range error on code, see details below

Tags: python, encryption

Code:

```
import random

randomnum = random.randint(1, 256)
enter = "john"
enterlen = (len(enter))
enterarray = [randomnum, enterlen]
i = 0

while i <= enterlen:
    enterarray.append(enter[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kdogg/PycharmProjects/starter/encode.py", line 9, in <module>
    enterarray.append(enter[i])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I am trying to make an encryption code using this array. I am supposed to fill up the array starting with a random number, then the length of the word I want to encode, then using a 1 to 1 code (`a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`, etc).

I am going to randomly multiply the numbers given (`a = 1`, `b = 2` etc) to get the numbers between two values(a could be between 1 and 25, etc, etc) and then convert it into hex to dim it down.

Example: let's say you put the word ABC. it would end up being something like `(100)(3)(1545784)` first the random number, then the word length, then each letter would be assigned a random number between two values, then everything would be converted to hex.
However, my array is not filling up even when using `append()`.

Comment: you don't need `while`-loop `enterarray = [randomnum, enterlen] + list(enter)` And if you want to use loop then use `for char in enter: enterarray.append(char)`

Comment: your are a saint. would you mind eloborating a little on why + list enter works. im a little new to python.

Comment: List has special function `list1.__add__(list2)` which can join two lists and `list1 + list2` runs this function. And you have one list `[randomnum, enterlen]`, and `list(text)` creates second list `["j", "o", "h", "n"]` - so you have `list1 + list2`

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Arrays start at 0 but `len()` returns a count of items, so you need to decrease this number. I recommend to change it in while loop to `i  < enterlen`. You should consider the use of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while i<enterlen:` instead of `while i<=enterlen:`
Because *i* in your case goes till 4 [5th character] whereas John just has 4 characters, so it gives index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access enter[4] which is not a valid index for that string value. Arrays are 0 based indexed therefore the only valid indices for enter are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

To solve your problem you must adjust your while loop to be i < enterlen. Thereby concluding when i = 4.

This will now print correctly [98, 4, 'j', 'o', 'h', 'n'].

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in other answer you need to use `<` instead of `<=` because list uses indexes from `0` to `len(enter)-1`

```
i = 0

while i < enterlen:
     enterarray.append(enter[i])
     i = i + 1
```

But instead `while` you could use `for`-loop and then you don't have problem with indexes.

```
for char in enter:
    enterarray.append(char)
```

For example convert ASCII chars to numbers

```
for char in enter:
    number = ord(char) - ord('A') + 1
    enterarray.append(number)
```

`A = 1`, `B = 2`, `C = 3`, etc. `a = 33`, `b = 34`, `c = 34`, etc.

If you want only lower case chars then you should use `ord('a')` instead of `ord('A') and you should convert`enter`to`lower()` to make sure you don't have upper case chars.

```
enter = enter.lower()
```

---

**BTW:** If you wanted only add chars to array then you could do

```
enterarray = [randomnum, enterlen] + list(enter)
```